# Python OpenCV not detecting face in training data

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

recently I have been working on a opencv face detection algorithm, and it was going rather smoothly at first. I uploaded 4 JPGs of myself(In a folder with my name) and it recognized me as myself. I tried adding 4 photos of my brother as well(In a separate folder with his name), and it was acting weird and recognized him as me instead of him. I then deleted my folder, so that only his folder was there for the images. I quickly tried to diagnose the problem and it is because my code is not detecting a face in his photos(The length of x_train is 0 where I print it). I did some googling and all of the "requirements" for a face to be detected seem to be met by these photos; so now I am wondering why this does not work.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import pickle
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()


base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
img_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, "images")


curr_id = 0

label_ids = {}

y_labels = []
x_train = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()

            if not label in label_ids:
                label_ids[label] = curr_id
                curr_id += 1

            id = label_ids[label] 



            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L")
            image_array = numpy.array(pil_image, "uint8")

            final_image = cv2.resize(image_array, (550, 550), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            equalized_image = cv2.equalizeHist(final_image)
            final_image = cv2.normalize(final_image, numpy.zeros((300, 300)), 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

            

            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor = 1.1, minNeighbors = 10)

            for (x, y, width, height) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y+height, x:x+width]
                x_train.append(roi)
                y_labels.append(id)

print(len(x_train))

with open("labels.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)

recognizer.train(x_train, numpy.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save("trainer.yml")
```

I am also getting this error too:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ProgrammingProjects\Python\FacialRegognition\faces-train.py", line 57, in <module>
    recognizer.train(x_train, numpy.array(y_labels))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\lbph_faces.cpp:362: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) Empty training data was given. You'll need more than one sample to learn a model. in function 'cv::face::LBPH::train'
```

When it recognized him as me, I tried to delete the folder that had the pictures of me and expected it to recognize him as him, however, it started throwing an error and I realized that it was not detecting a face in his photos.

Comment: the recognizer partitions the space of ALL POSSIBLE FACES according to what you give it. if you give it ONE CLASS, everything goes in that one class.

Comment: I'm confused on what you mean, but I believe you are saying that it is classifying his faces under my name. The thing is, it isn't even getting to that point; it is just not detecting his face in any of the sample data I gave it. Also, I had it print how many faces there were in my sample data pictures and in the 4 pictures it only saw 3. It seems to work fine in my camera, so I just don't know why it has trouble in the training date.

Comment: haar cascades are ancient tech. their performance is poor. detection is the issue, not the face recognition. OpenCV has a more thoroughly trained face cascade somewhere. it works for some amount of rotation of the face. it might even be that "the file" everyone uses received that update in recent years, so you should make sure you use a trained model from the latest release.